# Como eu consigo centralizar meu formulario dentro da minha div?

Tags: css, css3

estou tenndando centralizar meu formulario de pesquisa no centro da minha div mas nao estou conseguindo existe alguma propiedade em css que faca isso sem precisa de ganbiarra? aqui esta a pagina de desenvolvimento

***index.html***

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="#" >

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form action="search.php" method="GET" class="fc">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

***style.css***

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html body {
        background-color: ghostwhite;
}

body div {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    height: 123px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px dashed black;
}

div .fc   {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

vejam eu setei `margin: 0 auto;` na minha `div` e na minha class `.fc` mas nao esta funcinando

resultado n naavegador

[image: form centro]

Comment: Horizontalmente e verticalmente?

Comment: Para o `margin: 0 auto;` funcionar o seu `form` tem que ter uma largura fixa também!

Comment: nos dois, agora quando eu setei  o width ele ficou tronxo pendendo para a direita

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O form por default tem width de 100% do elemento pai. Tem de definir `text-align:center`

```css
form {
  text-align:center;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div>
            <form action="search.php" method="GET" class="fc">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

Pode definir também uma width e centrar o form, nota que centrar o form não é a mesma coisa que centrar os elemtos dentro dele, para isso tem o exemplo acima:

```css
form {
    border:1px solid;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }
```

```html
<div>
            <form action="search.php" method="GET" class="fc">
                    <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: valeu cara agora ficou direitinho +1 vlw

Comment: De nada @NikoBellic

Comment: alem de generoso ainda e modesto

Answer (score 2):

A única alteração simples que você deve fazer é essa:

- Em vez de DISPLAY:BLOCK digite - DISPLAY:FLEX. E mais nada!

TENTE ISSO. É MÁGICO!!!!!!!

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

html body {
        background-color: ghostwhite;
}

body div {
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    height: 123px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 2px dashed black;
}

div .fc   {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form action="search.php" method="GET" class="fc">
      <input type="text" autocomplete="on" name="q" placeholder="Digite a sua pesquisa" />
      <input type="submit" value="Tecle Enter" />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
```